# What can cause Google Search Console ownership by delegation to fail?

Tags: google-search-console

I just inherited management of three websites for a new client.  The previous agency did not add her as an admin to any of her sites in Google Search Console, Google Analytics, or Google Tag Manager.  I am in the process of fixing this.

I am an admin on her GA and GTM accounts, and a owner of her web properties in GSC (via delegation).

She is now an admin in GA and GTM.  I was able to successfully add her to GSC as an owner to one of her properties by delegation, but on the other two I get an error message:

> We weren't able to add my.client@gmail.com. Please try again later.

What can cause ownership by delegation to fail, especially when it works on another property?  As a stop-gap, I can see if I can get her to verify ownership herself with one of the other methods, but I would really prefer the delegation method.

Comment: The "Please try again later" portion of the message makes me think that the problem is caused by Google's bug.     I'd just wait a few days and try again.

Comment: Apparently, on the two sites I was having problems on, I was listed as a **Verified Owner by Delegation**, but the logs showed that **Reverification Failed**.  I verified via another method, and was then able to add my client.  Not sure if this is a real answer or just a fluke.